# How should we celebrate our birthday?

Tags: discussion

In three weeks, History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange will turn one year old. Congratulations on everyone who worked hard to make our first year in beta a success.

How should we mark the occasion? A discussion of what we've done right and wrong? A shout-out to our favorite questions and answers? Visions for the future? A combination of all of these?

Put your suggestions in answers to this question - one answer per question, please! - and we can figure out what we want to do.

Happy (early) birthday, HSM!

[image]

Comment: I don't even celebrate my own birthday, but I am quite sure my parents celebrated my first birthday. I love the cheer! This site is not so busy to the extent that we can't entertain some happy monumental moments in our own meta. Great celebratory pic HDE, and nice sentiments. Maybe we could just make noise here on this meta post. In any case, Happy Birthday HSM.SE!